# Map ExtJS Proxy AJAX response to model

Tags: javascript, json, model-view-controller, web-applications, extjs

### UPDATE:

*here is my reader/store - **not sure what to add to the reader to make this work***

```
Ext.define('YT.store.Videos', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
  model: 'YT.model.Video',
  autoLoad: true,
  proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url: 'https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos',
    reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'feed',
            record: 'entry',
            successProperty: 'success'
     },
    listeners: {
      exception: function(store, response, app){
        console.log('exception...');
        console.log(response);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

---

**Here is my model:**

```
Ext.define('YT.model.Video', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
  autoLoad: true,
  fields: [
    'title',
    'published',
    'content'
  ]
});
```

**Here is a sample response:**

```
{
  version: '1.0',
  encoding: 'UTF-8',
  feed: {
    junk: 'blahblahblahblah',
    entry: [
      title: {
        $t: 'title'
      },
      content: {
        encoding: 'flash/application',
        src: 'http://youtube.com/watch?q=someCatVideo'
      },
      published: {
        $t: '12-28-2012'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm not sure how to reconcile the two.

**I've tried...**

```
Ext.define('YT.model.Video', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
  autoLoad: true,
  fields: [
    {name: 'title', mapping: 'title.$t'},
    {name: 'published', mapping: 'published.$t'},
    {name: 'content', mapping: 'content.src'}
  ]
});
```

### Bonus:

Definitely looking for tips on how to debug the implementation of these techniques, I'm rather new to JavaScript MVC.

Comment: see my edited answer with working code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track with mapping, but you also need to define a reader where you specify [where your records are](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Json-property-root) in the JSON you get back - see official docs for good examples.
Incidentally, who thought $t was a good idea for a map key?

**EDIT**:
After your edits here is your working code:
http://jsfiddle.net/dbrin/mSJg3/

As far as debugging: the key for your issue was to clearly see the payload from the service (I used FireBug to inspect JSON object returned). Then mapping your Model class to fit the JSON object through mapping attribute and finally adjust JSON reader to let it know how to navigate your JSON payload (see my code example).
Once your exception listeners are not firing anymore (see code example for those again) that means you got your data into the store. To actually see the data I used Illuminations firebug plugin to inspect the data store. I saw only one record. What the heck? I observed id Property being set to some funky URL. This was happening by default as i did not specify an id attribute on the model. I resorted to spacifying idProperty to undefined to get around this funky behavior (see model code).

I used jsfiddle to quickly iterate through changes and running to see errors in the reader. Once I had no more errors I had jsfiddle show me the app I just build in such a way that I could use Illuminations plugin by using the show/light url: http://jsfiddle.net/dbrin/mSJg3/show/light/

Comment: Actually, it's Google's Youtube API with ?alt=json in the query string.  Its probably just some auto converted BS for lazy devs who hate XML like myself.  Just doing a quick hack/slash implementation or I'd probably just bite the bullet and use XML

Comment: thanks very much.  This is exactly what I needed to see.  You definitely completed my understanding of how ExtJS works.  Thank you soooo much!

Comment: Hilarious note, ran into this problem again and couldn't remember it, googled it, got here... HA! <3 SO